# Populate a Windows Form TreeView from a Visual SourceSafe repository (with status)

Tags: c#, treeview, command-prompt, windows-forms-designer, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to populate a TreeView from a Visual SourceSafe repository via Console Commands in a Windows Form. The only problem is, I need the "status" of the file (if it's checked in/checked out). I've already made local copies of the repo but it unfortunately doesn't show the status of the file.

Here's what my code looks like so far... I've been using the "Dir" command and also tried using the "Status" command but I can't figure out how to get Dir to populate the tree as well as Status:

```
public static string vssPath = @"C:\temp\VSS\";
public static string vssCommand = @"C:\VSS\win32\ss"; 

// initial load from VSS for TreeView
public static void ViewInitialVSS()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = vssCommand;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"Get $/Legacy -I-Y -GL {0}", vssPath);

    // TODO better option as it will also show the status... need to have a way to display it to Treeview... 
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"Dir {0} -E -R", vssPath);

    List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
}
```

And how I'm currently filling the treeview (without status):

```
public partial class CompProdtoVSSForm : Form
{
    public CompProdtoVSSForm()
    {
        // creates local copy of $/Legacy via console commands
        VSS.ViewInitialVSS();

        // TODO replace Test.testDirectory with vssPath
        InitializeComponent();
        ListDirectory(vCCFilesTreeView, Test.testDirectory);

        outputListBox_Paint(string.Format(@"Directory {0} Loaded", VSS.vssPath));
    }

    // recursively fills treeview, will need to grey out/filter ones considered "in use"
    private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }

    private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        }
        return directoryNode;
    }
```